# VB.Net - Button Style Modification

Tags: vb.net, button, styles, themes

I just like to ask how this Buttonstyle is called in .net:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVNuo.png

And How do I color the borders gray?
It should look like in the Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a "FlatStyle" button, you can set the style, text colour, border colour and mouse-over colour like so:

```
Button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
Button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
Button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray
Button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
```